# Terraform - VSphere - Cannot find OS family for guest ID “otherGuest”: No Permission

Tags: terraform, privileges, vsphere

I’ve been trying to script a clone operation in VSphere using Terraform.
I am able to **perform this clone manually** when using VSphere UI.

When running terraform plan, the executions fails with this error:

```
Error: cannot find OS family for guest ID “otherGuest”: NoPermission
```

As seen on [Terraform source code for VSphere module](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-vsphere/blob/cac9fff27921ab083e6ddd1f34989d54fa0214a2/vsphere/internal/vmworkflow/virtual_machine_clone_subresource.go), this is only happening because I’m customizing the cloned VM (`customize {}` section)… When skipping customization, `terraform plan` succeeds

I am not full administrator of the VSphere environment but I have quite some privileges enabled.

- **What would be the privileges I need to get in order to avoid this error?**

**main.tf**

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = "${var.vsphere_user}"
  password       = "${var.vsphere_password}"
  vsphere_server = "${var.vsphere_server}"

  # if you have a self-signed cert
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = "${var.vsphere_datacenter}"
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "src_datastore" {
  name          = "${var.vsphere_src_datastore}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "dst_datastore" {
  name          = "${var.vsphere_dst_datastore}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_resource_pool" "pool" {
  name          = "${var.vsphere_resource_pool}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

#data "vsphere_compute_cluster" "cluster" {
#  name          = "${var.vsphere_compute_cluster_name}"
#  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
#}

resource "vsphere_folder" "src_folder" {
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
  path          = "${var.vsphere_src_folder}"
  type          = "vm"
}

resource "vsphere_folder" "dst_folder" {
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
  path          = "${var.vsphere_dst_folder}"
  type          = "vm"
}

data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = "${var.vsphere_network}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm_clone" {
  name          = "${var.vsphere_virtual_machine_name_src}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "cloned_vm" {
  name             = "${var.vsphere_virtual_machine_name_dst}"
  resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
  datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.dst_datastore.id}"

  num_cpus = "${var.guest_vcpu}"
  memory   = "${var.guest_memory}"
  guest_id = "otherGuest" //${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm_clone.guest_id}"

  scsi_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm_clone.scsi_type}"

  network_interface {
    network_id   = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
    adapter_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm_clone.network_interface_types[0]}"
  }

  disk {
    label = "disk0"
    size = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm_clone.disks.0.size}"
    eagerly_scrub    = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm_clone.disks.0.eagerly_scrub}"
    thin_provisioned = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm_clone.disks.0.thin_provisioned}"
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm_clone.id}"

    customize {

      linux_options {
        host_name = "${var.guest_host_name}"
        domain    = "${var.guest_domain}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
# Provider Vcenter
vsphere_user = "user"
vsphere_password = "pass"
vsphere_server = "vsphere.mydomain.com"

# Infrastructure
vsphere_datacenter = "Palo Alto"
vsphere_src_datastore = "MyDatastore"
vsphere_dst_datastore = "MyDatastore"
vsphere_resource_pool = "MyResourcePool"
vsphere_network = "192.168.1.x_NET"
vsphere_compute_cluster_name = "Testing Cluster"
vsphere_src_folder = "Test"
vsphere_dst_folder = "Prod"

# Infor VMware clone
# Escapes with "\\" are mandatory
vsphere_virtual_machine_name_src = "vm-to-clone"
vsphere_virtual_machine_name_dst = "cloned-vm"

# Infor VMware
guest_vcpu = "4"
guest_memory = "8192"
guest_ipv4_address = "192.168.1.15"
guest_ipv4_netmask = "24"
guest_ipv4_gateway = "192.168.1.1"
guest_dns_servers = "192.168.1.254"
guest_host_name = "test-01"

# Edit
guest_domain = "mydomain.com"
```

Comment: This is the only API where I found the `otherGuest` reference: https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere/doc/vim.vm.GuestOsDescriptor.GuestOsIdentifier.html

Comment: And btw, I don't see a value for `guest_domain` in your `terraform.tfvars`, maybe that could be the cause, unless you forgot to copy it. :)

Comment: @MarkoE I've seen this VSphere documentation but it simply list the different guest IDs that exist, nothing related to potential privileges if we need to use them.
Regarding `guest_domain`, I did not have this variable in `terraform.tfvars`, I'll try that, thanks :)

**Edit**: adding this variable generates the same error

Comment: Btw, which version of Terraform are you using? It looks like `0.11.x`. I am asking because of this: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/deprecating-terraform-0-11-support-in-terraform-providers.

Comment: @MarkoE I'm using version 1.0.1 and Vsphere module v2.0.2. I'm seeing v1.0.5 is released but don't seem to be fixing things for this problem. 
Do you think it might be more related to Terraform than to VSphere privileges regarding the VM guest Identifiers (here otherGuest) ?

Comment: Not sure, I was thinking that it could be related to the older version of VSphere provider where the configuration option still wasn't available, but now I'm thinking it has something to do with VSphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, the issue was coming from VSphere privileges.
The host VM (the one to clone) was hosted on a machine for which I didn't have access and wasn't shown in the Hosts list on VCenter.

This access was not required when manually cloning the VM from the UI but it was required when using the API.

Thus, the solution was to edit my user privileges and select **"Propagate to children" at the Datacenter level** to ensure I had access to all the hosts and clusters.

No specific privileges was required to be added, just the basic ones applied to the correct level.